# How to Cache a .htaccess & .htpasswd/Authorization Required Offline

Tags: html, .htaccess, caching, basic-authentication, .htpasswd

I have a working website with a verification/login using .htaccess & .htpasswd. When trying to cache it I get the error:

```
Application Cache Error event: Resource fetch failed (403) http://fman.cf/.htaccess
```

I'm not sure if their is another way to have an offline verification but here is my Offline.appcache file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# Cache Manifest Version: 1.0
# For Offline Usage
# Reminder: JQuery

CACHE

/Javascript.js
/Styles.css
/RPS.jpg
/RPS.html
/Miji.html
/Murderer.jpeg
/Lottery.png
/403.html
/404.html
/.htaccess
/.htpasswd
/.quarantine/*
/.tmb/*

NETWORK

*

FALLBACK

/404.html

# Last Update:
# 6/2/2015
```

.htaccess:

```
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW ERRORPAGEID:asdfasdf
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE asdfasdf:ERRORPAGEID


# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW ERRORPAGEID:adsfasdf
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE asdfasdf:ERRORPAGEID


AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache







# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW PWPROTECTID:passblahblah
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthUserFile /home/myid/public_html//.htpasswd
Require user admin
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE blablah:PWPROTECTID
```

.htpasswd:

```
USERNAME:MY_PASSWORD
```

**NOTE: All of the comments in the .htaccess were placed their by my hosting service, I did change all the actualy numbers/words/passwords to random stuff.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.htaccess` files are not available offline, because the server (Apache) uses them, not the browser. This is an important point which I think you did not understand yet. 
The server looks into the file and *uses* it to offer login, the *login* itself does not happen in the `.htaccess` file. A standalone `.htaccess` file doesn't do anything, it only contains text.

Files starting with `.ht` are blocked to the public by default Apache configuration.

There is no way you can implement an offline login using HTML.

The `.htaccess` can be cached serverside in two ways:

1. Move the configuration to a standalone apache configuration permanently loaded (instead of dynamically loaded .htaccess).
2. Put the .htaccess file on a ramdisk.

None of those methods would speed up anything significantly, nor would it allow the user to login offline.